# Echoing php into javascript variable not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, dom

So I have it set so when I click a button it creates an XMLHttpRequest object which is used to get the data I want.

onclick button runs

```
function allcontactstable() {
    var url = "php_scripts/allcontactstable.php";
    tablerequest.open("GET", url, true);
    tablerequest.onreadystatechange = inserttable;
    tablerequest.send(null);
}
```

php is

```
$mysql = mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "");
$db = mysql_select_db("arw29");

$query = "Select `firstname`, `lastname`, `email` from `contacts`";

$result = mysql_query($query);

$output = null;
$output .= '<table>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $output .= '<tr>';
    $output .= '<td>'.$row['firstname'].'</td>';
    $output .= '<td>'.$row['lastname'].'</td>';
    $output .= '<td>'.$row['email'].'</td>';
    $output .= '</tr>';
}
$output .= '</table>';

echo $output;

mysql_close();
```

and the callback function is

```
function inserttable() {
if (tablerequest.readyState == 4) {
    if (tablerequest.status == 200) {
        var response = tablerequest.responseText;
        document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = response;
    }
    else {
        alert("Error: " + tablerequest.statusText);
    }
}
}
```

What the result is that the div on my webpage does not contain the formatted table like I was expecting, and instead contains the string

```
'
'; while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ $output .= ''; $output .= ''.$row['firstname'].''; $output .= ''.$row['lastname'].''; $output .= ''.$row['email'].''; $output .= ''; } $output .= ''; echo $output; mysql_close(); ?>'
```

Tried searching and could not find anything that related to this.

Comment: It looks like your server is not executing your PHP and just returning the contents of the PHP file.

Comment: Missing the `<?php` tag at the top of your PHP script?